# MySQL multiple order set

Tags: mysql

I have a query with an order

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, '1,5,3,4,2'), end_date ASC
```

but what I would like is any record with status 1 to be ordered end_date ASC and any status 2 ordered by end_date DESC and the others ordered by end_date ASC.

Can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
  ORDER BY
    IF(status < 2, status, 3),
    IF(status = 2, TO_DAYS(end_date) * -1, TO_DAYS(end_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

Refining Devart's answer...

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
  ORDER BY find_in_set(status, '1,5,3,4,2')
  CASE
    WHEN (status = 2) then TO_DAYS(end_date) * -1
    ELSE TO_DAYS(end_date)
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 queries to get your different sorts, then get the UNION of the queries.

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE status!=2 
 ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, '1,5,3,4'), end_date ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE status=2 ORDER BY end_date DESC)
) AS table_sort ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, '1,5,3,4,2')
```

Since you want the status 2 records last, technically you wouldn't need to SELECT on the UNION and ORDER it, but I added that in case you wanted a different sort order.

Comment: I will give that a go soon. I had 2 separate queries previously but I have added pagination so needed them to be a single query string. Thanks